# Master/Detail Example with asp.net Programmatically

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview

does anyone know any example to make a master/detail gridview/detailsview Programmatically?. I really appreciatte if you could give me some example of how i must code that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.vkinfotek.com/detailsview/gridview-detailsview-master-detail-example.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16779/GridView-DetailsView-Master-Detail-Control

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for some example with 2 gridviews when i click  in some row of the master grid, my detail grid must be updated programatically. Do you have any other resource?